# Javascript Save Local Data

Tags: javascript, json, local

I made a Local Web Game using Javascript and a very basic html page so I don't need and want to use a Server for my game !

But now I want to save some data (record for example) . So i made a Json file which I managed to read using `$.getJSON` and I was wondering if I could write in my json file using only Javascript ?

I don't want to use any php script !

I look forward to your response !

Comment: Do you want to store the data in the local storage?

Comment: you'll need some kind of server-side solution if you want to save data on the server.

Comment: Pay attention, that dealing with files are only in browsers possible that a compatible with the last javascript version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you have a structure named scores.

You can stringify it and store it in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) :

```
function addScore(newScore) {
    scores.push(newScore);
    localStorage['scores'] = JSON.stringify(scores);
}
```

And then restore it at start of your program :

```
var scores = localStorage['scores'] ? JSON.parse(localStorage['scores']) : [];
```

Comment: Right now, I run my html file with WampServer. With localStorage, is the data saved if I close my Browser and open it again ? 
The best way would have been to directly write my Json File !

Comment: Yes, localStorage is persistent between sessions. That's the whole point. I use it to store user preferences.

Comment: I'll try it as soon as possible! Thanks very much !

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 [WebSQL](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/) as sql database or HTML5 [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) as no sql database.