# Is there a way to make a login system in html and javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know how to make the layout but I want to know how to make a login system that saves a username and password without PHP, with Javascript or JQuery.

Comment: if you're using jQuery look at `$.cookie`. for normal javascript (more fuss) see `document.cookie`.

Comment: forget it... Storing sensitive data client side is a no go

Comment: Don't make a login system with only a client side programming language. Might as well make no login system at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, you cannot enforce the security of code running inside the user's web browser in a way that would be necessary for a meaningful login system. The processing model of the web requires you to process some form of input submitted by the client (e.g. a username and password) against some private logic or data on the server (e.g. a one-way hash of the password in a database). It is also server-side code which needs to know that a user is logged in, and what permissions that grants them.

If you like JS *as a language*, you could look into node.js, which runs JS as the server-side platform rather than some other language like PHP or Ruby.

The only other alternative, I think, is the extremely limited "HTTP Basic Auth", which lets you forbid access to certain URLs based on a manually maintained list of passwords.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML and Javascript everything is done on the client side.  Without have some type of server side system, anything can be trapped on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Google offers some ways to use libraries and their servers to build stable login solutions.
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store data at server side, then **No**, you can not do using client script.

But if you want to store it locally, then you can use HTML5 [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Also refer [javascript-save-local-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157529/javascript-save-local-data)